# How to use custom tables in any views?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a custom table in drupal database. I need to use this table data in views . For this I have used schema module but its displaying only new views. But I need to use these table data in all views in our site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hook_views_query_alter` and alter the views query by merging your custom query with the views SQL query itself.

Also there is an option in "advanced" section - theme suggestions
There you can write your custom query to fetch results into tabular format.

Comment: You can create a custom module using hook_view_api() and hook_view_data().In hook_view_data() you can add the table and fields that you want to display in view.You can go through the link given below:     https://www.sitepoint.com/exposing-tables-views-drupal-7

Comment: After adding fields you can see the table name in view content type dropdown

Answer (score 1):

While `hook_views_data()` definitely allows to expose the custom table to the Views module, I would recommend you to use one of the following modules, so that you don't have to write code every time you create a custom table.

- [Views Expose Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_expose_tables)
- [Data Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data)